# Basic interest question

Tags: economics

I have a really stupid question. I'm trying to figure out how long it will take someone to pay off their credit debt. So this is what I'm given:

Someone owes $800

Have an annual interest rate of 12%

And they pay off $60 a month.

How many years will it take for them to pay off their debt? Can I just use a simply I=PRT formula to figure it out? I feel like I'm overthinking it.

Comment: What do you mean by $I=PRT$?

Comment: the basic interest formula. I don't think I can.

Comment: What kind of interest is it, compound or simple?

Comment: compounded monthly

Comment: skullripper I´ve posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to use the monthly interest rate $i_{12}=\frac{0.12}{12}=\frac{i}{12}=0.01$

Then you set up an equation. The compounded loan (L) minus the sum of the compounded payments (annuities) is at most zero. Without the values the inequality is

$$L\cdot (1+\frac{i}{12})^{12\cdot n}-a\cdot  
 \frac{(1+\frac{i}{12})^{12\cdot n}-1}{\frac{i}{12}} \normalsize                     
\leq 0$$

We can use the equality for calculation and then solve for n. At the end we can regard the inequality.

$$L\cdot (1+\frac{i}{12})^{12\cdot n}-a\cdot  
 \frac{(1+\frac{i}{12})^{12\cdot n}-1}{\frac{i}{12}}\normalsize                      
= 0$$

Inserting the values and bring the negative term to the RHS.

$$800\cdot 1.01^{12\cdot n}=60\cdot  
 \frac{1.01^{12\cdot n}-1}{0.01}$$

You can start by multiplying both sides by $0.01$

$$8\cdot 1.01^{12\cdot n}=60\cdot \left(  
1.01^{12\cdot n}-1\right) =   60\cdot  
1.01^{12\cdot n}   -60            
$$

Subtracting $8\cdot 1.01^{12\cdot n}$ and adding $60$ on both sides of the equation.

$$60=52\cdot  
1.01^{12\cdot n}                   
$$

Can you proceed?

Comment: Thanks! Should I just solve for n then?

Comment: Yes, that´s true.

Comment: Thanks! Can I use these general steps to to solve for other problems with the same problem format.

Comment: @skullripper675 Yes, if the problems are of the same type. You can anticipate variations as well. For instance, if the compounding is every 3 month (quarter) you use $i_4=\frac{0,12}{4}=0.03$ instead of $i_{12}=\frac{0,12}{12}$